# Adding figures into a report, How to cite?

Tags: citations, academic-writing

I am writing my first ever thesis these days. In order to describe a feature extraction methodology, I am going to insert a figure to my thesis and that figure is taken from the original paper in which the methodology has been proposed. That paper has already been cited by me in my thesis.

My questions are

1. Can I copy the figure from the paper directly and add to my report?
2. If I can, how should I add the reference to the figure I am going to insert?
3. Since I have already cited the paper, do I need to add the reference to the figure separately?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your university have a particular style guide that they follow?

Comment: We are advised to use IEEE referencing style

Comment: @MonicaCellio Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the figure directly from your paper because the work is yours to use as you wish but you will need to reference the figure, at the place it is used and in your list of References.  You can find a thorough explanation with examples at [APA Citation Style, 6th edition: Figures](http://libguides.gwumc.edu/c.php?g=27779&p=170358).

If you cited the figure originally from another source then you should use that source but are allowed to use the "As cited in" technique.

Good Luck!